# Display current layout WITHOUT using Windows's language bar

Tags: windows-7, language, switch, quicklaunch, software-conflict

Basically I *love* quick launch and pinning is not for me, I can't just pin 50 apps, nor pin them to start menu / use the `win + type` method.

Anyway, Quick Launch works perfectly under Win7 IF you don't use the language bar. If you use it, sometimes (or always) it may fail to start/appear, you have to readd it.

So my question is: Is there a tray app, a RainMeter way to show this? (First would be better).

Thanks. (Best would be if I could switch layout globally but that train is gone. (Look at the changing global layout. Thank you Microsoft. (Irony included)).

Comment: Can I ask if where your language bar is? I use it and I've never had a problem. Does your other language remap the winkey or something?

Comment: Yes it does. Z instead of Y and I can't write éáűőúóí without it. But with my answer, that languageindicator application solved ALL the problems at once. Kudos for the developer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this application:
http://www.languageindicator.com/

It does what I wanted to code AND more.

Answer (score 0):

You could put display the onscreen keyboard. (start, run osk)

However, this is not ideal as it is pretty big, and doesn't display the layouts name, just the layout itself.

I feel your pain with the global layout issue though.

Comment: Is there a ...a ... method/C# code for this ? If yes, a tray app would be simply OK, which would say EN, HU, like the bar does. Will try this out... (Stack Overflow will help I guess. :))